# Get selected multiple posts/pages by ID in Wordpress API using React/Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs

So, I'm having no trouble getting *all* posts from my WP API using this endpoint:

```
`${appUrl}/wp-json/wp/v2/pages`;
```

But, I can't for the life of me figure out the syntax to query multiple, specific pages by ID,
I've been trawling for hours now - is this even possible (of course it is - I'm just being a numpty)??

Any tips would be most welcome.

Cheers

Terry

Comment: Have you tried `appUrl + '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?include[]=470&include[]=469'` where `470` and `469` are example ids?

Comment: Thanks Tholle, but it didn't work.

Comment: Turns out it did, I had an extra backtick - many thanks!! :)

Comment: I upvoted your comment - but it's not an 'answer' so I can't accept it...If you want to post it as an answer I'll happily accept it and upvote.

Comment: i've now deleted my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query posts by ids by passing a `include` query parameter array containing the ids you want.

```
const ids = [469, 470];
const url = `${appUrl}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?${ids.map(id => `include[]=${id}`).join("&")}`;
```

Comment: Thanks. It saved a lot of time and request.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is like a year ago but i couldn't seem to find a way to get all pages by id and came across this post, i tried the include[]=123&include[]=321 but it just returned blank, I finally found out you have to add a status. in my case i choose any. Hope this helps someone.

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?status=any&include[]=129&include[]=131
```